# Need help in pulling Firestore data using the same function

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, google-cloud-firestore

[image]

I am trying to pull firestore data.
In the image as you can see I want to check if the data in firestore is a student or not.
I tried with snapshot and all the others on the previous stack overflow, but nothing helped.
This is my first time posting it here, so sorry if I did not follow any rules.

I want to do something like this

```
    if(student == "1")
            {
                Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            }
            else
            {
            Intent i = new Intent(this, SubjectsActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            }
```

[image]

```
        import android.content.DialogInterface;
        import android.content.Intent;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.text.TextUtils;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.widget.Button;
        import android.widget.EditText;
        import android.widget.ProgressBar;
        import android.widget.TextView;
        import android.widget.Toast;
    
        import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
        import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
       import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
    
    import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
    import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
    import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
    import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
    import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
    import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
    import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
    import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
    
    // [START fs_include_dependencies]
    // [END fs_include_dependencies]
    
    public class Login_TA extends AppCompatActivity {
      EditText mEmail,
      mPassword;
      Button mLoginBtn;
      TextView mCreateBtn,
      forgotTextLink;
      ProgressBar progressBar;
      FirebaseAuth fAuth;
      FirebaseFirestore fStore;
      String userID;
      String student;
    
      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login__t);
    
        mEmail = findViewById(R.id.Email);
        mPassword = findViewById(R.id.password);
        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        fAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mLoginBtn = findViewById(R.id.loginBtn);
        mCreateBtn = findViewById(R.id.createText);
        forgotTextLink = findViewById(R.id.forgotPassword);
        fStore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    
        mLoginBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {@Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
    
            String email = mEmail.getText().toString().trim();
            String password = mPassword.getText().toString().trim();
    
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
              mEmail.setError("Email is Required.");
              return;
            }
    
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
              mPassword.setError("Password is Required.");
              return;
            }
    
            if (password.length() < 6) {
              mPassword.setError("Password Must be >= 6 Characters");
              return;
            }
    
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    
            // authenticate the user
    
            fAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener < AuthResult > () {@Override
    
              public void onComplete(@NonNull Task < AuthResult > task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                  FirebaseUser fUser = fAuth.getCurrentUser();
                  userID = fAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
    
                  //I want the data to be here so I can redrect accordingly
    
                  startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));
                  Toast.makeText(Login_TA.this, "Log in Succesfully ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    
                } else {
                  Toast.makeText(Login_TA.this, "Error ! " + task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
    
              }
            });
    
          }
        });
```

Edit *****************
THis is what I am trying

```
public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if(task.isSuccessful()){
                            FirebaseUser fUser = fAuth.getCurrentUser();
                            userID = fAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();


                            if(userID != null){
                                DocumentReference docref = db.collection("users").document(userID);
                                docref.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                            DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                                            if (document.exists()) {
                                                String student = document.getString("Student?");
                                                Toast.makeText(Login_TA.this, student, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                if(student == "0"){
                                                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),AssignmentTAActivity.class));
                                                }else {
                                                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SettingsActivity.class));
                                                }

                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                });

                            }
```

Comment: This should be possible with snapshot. Can you add to the question what have you tried and what was the effect?

Comment: Thanks @vitooh, I edited what I am trying . It just goes to the else part , and I believe the reason is its not reading the part correct.